# Hashchange event not working as expected in IE iframe

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hashchange

The hashchange event in IE doesn't seem to fire when triggered from within an iframe from an anchor targeted to its same-domain parent window.  Consider the following super basic HTML pages (intentionally not using libraries like jQuery for simplicity).

parent.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parent</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onhashchange = function () {
            alert(window.location.hash);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="#A">A</a></p>
    <iframe src="child.htm"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<p>Loaded at ' + new Date() + '</p>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

child.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Child</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="parent.htm#B" target="_top">B</a></p>
    <p><a href="parent.htm#C" target="_parent">C</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="top.location='parent.htm#D';">D</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, all four links (A,B,C,D) will result in an alert.  In IE, links A and D will trigger the alert, but B and C will cause a full page reload with no alert.  I couldn't find any documentation that explains this as expected behavior.

I can hack in a jQuery shim that fixes IE child links by attaching event handlers, but is there any way I can get IE to recognize the hashchange?

Comment: +1 also interested in this

Comment: I've gone through a lot trying to perfect this on my website. The best solution available today is with javascript's `top.history.pushState`. Otherwise, `top.location.hash` is good too. Relying on pure HTML for achieving this is hopeless for cross-browser support. One last possibility is to write a full path to your link which would match the parent document and only differ in the hash part. That's because if the iframe is in a subdirectory, what seemed like `/parent.htm#C` actually becomes `/directory/parent.htm#C`, eliciting a reload.